# make: target with variable suffix

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I'm using GNU make to build my own project and I support several versions of  it. I have one `Makefile` to handle this task. One of my rules (for cleaning dist) looks like this:

```
default_version := 2.4

clean-dist: clean-dist-$(default_version)
clean-dist-%:
    $(eval default_version := $(subst clean-dist-,,$@))
    if [ "$(default_version)" != "all" ]; then \
            rm -rf $(BUILDDIR)/program-src-$(default_version); \
    else \
            rm -rf $(BUILDDIR)/program-src-*; \
    fi
```

Please give me advice, what is the best way to do this task? 
Is my solution ok?

I prefer `ifeq` by `make` but it works on phase 1 of parsing `Makefile`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `$*` automatic variable in the  recipes  of your pattern rules. It is expanded as the stem, that is, `all` for `clean-dist-%` if the target is `clean-dist-all`:

```
default_version := 2.4

clean-dist: clean-dist-$(default_version)

clean-dist-%:
    if [ "$*" != "all" ]; then \
            rm -rf $(BUILDDIR)/program-src-$*; \
    else \
            rm -rf $(BUILDDIR)/program-src-*; \
    fi
```

You could also have a specific rule for `clean-dist-all` and a pattern rule for the other `clean-dist-something`. Make will prefer the specific rule if it has the choice:

```
default_version := 2.4

clean-dist: clean-dist-$(default_version)

clean-dist-all:
    rm -rf $(BUILDDIR)/program-src-*

clean-dist-%:
    rm -rf $(BUILDDIR)/program-src-$*
```

Finally, you can factor all this with the `patsubst` make function:

```
default_version := 2.4

clean-dist: clean-dist-$(default_version)

clean-dist-%:
    rm -rf $(BUILDDIR)/program-src-$(patsubst all,*,$*)
```

Note: as this `rm -rf ...` stuff is quite dangerous, it would probably be wise to test the solution you decided to use (for instance by adding `echo` before the `rm -rf ...` commands) before actually using it.